# Is there a tableView function that is the inverse of editActionsForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, listener

I currently have an extremely complex tableView setup. I found that there is code that I can trigger during the function 'editActionsForRowAtIndexPath' to make it happen at the correct moment. I want to trigger code returning from this point as well.

To be specific, 'editActionsForRowAtIndexPath' is called when I click on the little red edit symbol on the left side of the cell. I use this moment to change my highlighted pin on a map to a red highlight. I want to unhighlight the pin from red when the cell becomes unselected for delete. I can't find a function that directly does this.

I am mainly interested in Swift, but I can translate Objective C 99% of the time, so that works as well.

[image]

Comment: didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath

Comment: that does not get called until after tableView.editting == false. When you click the cell again, tableView.editting == true, but the cell is no longer selected for delete.

Comment: just for clarity - you want the highlight for a pin to appear and disappear depending on whether it's associated cell is showing the Delete tab on the right?

Comment: Yes and I have the functionality fully working except that I want to unhighlight it when unselected.

Comment: For lack of a better answer, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210340/how-to-get-touch-outside-current-cell-in-ios-swift

Comment: It still looks decent when it remains highlighted till i am Done editting or click another cell, but decent isn't good enough for my Enterprise App.

Comment: @Shades didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not activate at this point.

Comment: actually, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath never get called with my setup. What initiates them? only dragging guestures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you for those of you that tried to help. The solution I ended up going with that seemed the cleanest was like so:

```
class ThisViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource {

    var tapView: ClickThroughView?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        //code for delete being shown goes here

        tapView = ClickThroughView(frame: tableView.frame)
        tapView?.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tapView!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(tapView!)
        return nil
    }
}

extension ThisViewController: HandleViewTapDelegate {
    func handleTap() {

        //code for delete going away goes here

        tapView?.removeFromSuperview()
        tapView = nil
    }
}

protocol HandleViewTapDelegate {
    func handleTap()
}

class ClickThroughView: UIView {
    var delegate: HandleViewTapDelegate?

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        delegate?.handleTap()
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the default red delete button is under your cell and make your cell slide to left. So Sliding cell back is a better way to implement this. Just make a transform to cell's content view when it will begin editing and reset when end editing.
The other way is to add target-action in your custom cell. And register notification for editing mode. It's easy and clear but not elegant.

Comment: I am trying to make an App similar to Zillow, and am realizing more and more that you just have to fake functionality existing because iOS default design locks down how much functionality you have in too many ways. I agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

In the 'editActionsForRowAtIndexPath' function you define the actions that the table view rows will have. In there you can say what will happen when that button is selected. This is a way of knowing when they hit the delete button.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var actions = [UITableViewRowAction]()
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Remove") { (action, indexPath) in
         //Here you can unhighlight the pin
    }
    return [delete]
}
```

To know when they stop editing you can use the function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //Here you can unhighlight the pin
}
```

Thanks @Shades for the help

Comment: didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath gets called when tableView.editting == false.  I already know how to handle the delete action. I want to know how to handle what happens when they don't click the delete button and they are still editting.

Comment: I grabbed every tableView function I could find and dry fired it with a print statement and it's name. I can't find any function that handles that click. Making a view that covers everything except for the delete button with an onTap listener seems like my only option at this point.

Comment: If you are going to do that then create a tap gesture recognizer

Comment: That is what I was referring to. It just seems like a really messy solution.